# Why my RMI socket sends only one byte?

Tags: java, sockets, encryption

Im working in a project. I want to encrypt the information between a RMI client and server. I was following some tutorials like http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/j2sdk-1.4.2/guide/rmi/socketfactory/index.html. They encrypt using a XOR method.

Things go ok. I mean, the information is encrypted and decrypted without problem, but when i capture data packets with Wireshark, all of them have a size of 1 byte.

I have analyzed XorInputStream and XorOutputStream classes, changing read and writes methods but i got nothing. Only data packets with one byte.

Im thinking that could be a Socket or ServerSocket class problem, with some property about the socket buffer size.

I want to resolve this, because the application uses a hundred communication messages to send only a few words.

I tried to modify write method's in the stream class looking for a buffering process, to send 4 bytes in a burst:

```
byte buf[] = new byte[4];
int i=0;

 public void write(int b) throws IOException {
   if(i<=3){
     buf[i]=(byte)((b ^ pattern) & 0xFF);
     i++;
   }
   else{
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            out.write(buf[j]);
        i=0;
        buf[i]=(byte)((b ^ pattern) & 0xFF);
        i++;
   }
}
```

But my program sends only a few bytes and got freeze.

Here is my full project:

https://mega.co.nz/#!pN0nUZTZ!G35QZxAgeZyzNg5Te8-ZlIjZmNK9wn8-0Cdj19nBOdY

If someone knows anything about this problem, it would be very helpful.

Thank u.

Comment: Last time you posted this you were told the code must be posted here. Nothing has changed.

Comment: And of course posting a .RAR file on some third party web site is going to cut your target audience even further, clearly to zero in this case. But why you're buffering individual writes this way is a mystery. All you need is a `BufferedOutputStream` between you and the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank u! solved. Have to extend BufferedOutputStream instead Filter at custom out/inputstream class

Comment: If the problem is solved, please consider marking your solution as the accepted answer. Otherwise it will stay in the list of unanswered questions. Thank you!